# How to have a mocked method behaves differently depends on how many times it's called

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

Is there anyway we can have a mocked method behaves differently depending on how many times this mocked method gets called?

eg.

if you have a method called

```
public boolean mockedmMethod() {
    //logic here
}
```

you want it mocked this way:

when 1st time mockedMethod() gets called, return `true`.

2nd time, 3rd time the following times it gets called... , return `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found out that:

```
Mockito.when(mockedMethod()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
```

also does the trick.

Comment: you may also give multiple values in one .thenReturn(true, false, true). Firs invocation will return firs, second -- second, third -- third and any invocation after last value has been returned, will return last value.

Answer (score 2):

Does that fullfil your need ?

```
given(mock.mockedMethod())
        .willReturn(true, true, false, false)
        .willReturn(true)
        .willThrow(IllegalStateException.class)
        .will(execute_my_custom_answer());
```

Comment: given() is from BDDMockito, yes, it sorts me out. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah sorry I like BDD style syntax better than the normal one, though it should work the same. Even for the void method stubbing syntax `willDoNothing().willDoNothing().willThrow(NPE.class).given(mock).mockedMethod();`